# Scala context bounds

Tags: scala, context-bound

Using context bounds in scala you can do stuff like

```
trait HasBuild[T] {
  def build(buildable: T): Something
}

object Builders {
  implict object IntBuilder extends HasBuild[Int] {
    override def build(i: Int) = ??? // Construct a Something however appropriate
  }
}

import Builders._
def foo[T: HasBuild](input: T): Something = implicitly[HasBuild[T]].build(1)
val somethingFormInt = foo(1)
```

Or simply

```
val somethingFromInt = implicitly[HasBuild[Int]].build(1)
```

How could I express the type of a `Seq` of any elements that have an appropriate implicit `HasBuild` object in scope? Is this possible without too much magic and external libraries?

`Seq[WhatTypeGoesHere]` - I should be able to find the appropriate `HasBuild` for each element

This obviously doesn't compile:

```
val buildables: Seq[_: HasBuild] = ???
```

Comment: Your example doesn't use a context bound anywhere. It uses implicits.

Comment: You are right, updated. Also feel free to update the title if you know the name of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean an existential type? like `val buildables: Seq[HasBuild[_]] = Seq(IntBuilder, SomeStringBuilder)`

Comment: Nope. I'd like to have a `Seq` of _anything_ for which there is an implicit `HasBuild` in scope.

Comment: So: `def foo[T: HasBuild](input: Seq[T])`?

Comment: Basically I'd like to be able to handle unrelated types in a common way (e.g.: `build`), without the user wrapping them in some kind of adapter manually - and enforce by the compiler, that the types actually _can_ be handled. Not sure if the purpose is clear.

Comment: What you are suggesting wouldn't work for like `foo(Seq(1, "a"))` if both `Int` and `String` had an appropriate `HasBuild` in scope.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a type with a context bound", context bound is simply a syntactic sugar for a method or class definition, so it can't be magically extracted from a method if I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you want `foo(Seq(1, "a"))`, you'd need an implicit `HasBuilder[Any]`. Otherwise, what type would you expect the compiler to infer? If you want the compiler to automagically extract the type information from the underlying concrete type, I'm not sure that's something you can easily do.

Comment: I think you got it @VictorMoroz. Do you know about any other idiomatic way of "attaching" functionality to unrelated types, then taking a Sequence of types that have this functionality?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I don't want an implicit object for any. Basically that way I could take a seq of anything and do the type checking runtime which is not what I want.

Comment: @bali182 That's exactly what I thought, I know that's something you wouldn't want to do. But I don't see a way of attaching implicit evidences of types the way you want it.

Comment: `Seq(1,  "a")` has a type `Seq[Any]`, if you don't want `Any` simply create a base class and derive all your classes from it. Obviously `Int` and `String` won't work that way.

Comment: The issue is I can't (and don't want to) derive them from a base class. Thanks guys, I have to come up with something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Basically I'd like to be able to handle unrelated types in a common way (e.g.: build), without the user wrapping them in some kind of adapter manually - and enforce by the compiler, that the types actually can be handled. Not sure if the purpose is clear.

Something you can do:

```
case class HasHasBuild[A](value: A)(implicit val ev: HasBuild[A])
object HasHasBuild {
  implicit def removeEvidence[A](x: HasHasBuild[A]): A = x.value
  implicit def addEvidence[A: HasBuild](x: A): HasHasBuild[A] = HasHasBuild(x)
}
```

and now (assuming you add a `HasBuild[String]` for demonstration):

```
val buildables: Seq[HasHasBuild[_]] = Seq(1, "a")
```

compiles, but

```
val buildables1: Seq[HasHasBuild[_]] = Seq(1, "a", 1.0)
```

doesn't. You can use methods with implicit `HasBuild` parameters when you have only a `HasHasBuild`:

```
def foo1[A](x: HasHasBuild[A]) = {
  import x.ev // now you have an implicit HasBuild[A] in scope
  foo(x.value)
}

val somethings: Seq[Something] = buildables.map(foo1(_))
```

Comment: It was actually incomplete. I've extended it to show how you would call methods like `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, contrary to some of the comments, you are relying on context bounds. Requesting an implicit type class instance for a `T` is what you call a "context bound".

What you want is achievable, but not trivial and certainly not without other libraries.

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.ToList
import shapeless._
import shapeless.poly_

object builder extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseGeneric[T : HasBuilder] = {
    at[T](obj => implicitly[HasBuilder[T]].build(obj))
  }
}

class Builder[L <: HList](mappings: L) {
  def build[HL <: HList]()(
    implicit fn: Mapper.Aux[builder.type, L, HL],
    lister: ToList[Something]
  ) = lister(mappings map fn)

  def and[T : HasBuilder](el: T) = new Builder[T :: L](el :: mappings)
}


object Builder {
  def apply[T : HasBuilder](el: T) = new Builder(el :: HNil)
}
```

Now you might be able to do stuff like:

```
Builder(5).and("string").build()
```

This will call out the `build` methods from all the individual implcit type class instances and give you a list of the results, where every result has type `Something`. It relies on the fact that all the build methods have a lower upper bound of `Something`, e.g as per your example:

```
trait HasBuild[T] {
  def build(buildable: T): Something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to do it dependency free. The solution @Alexey suggested wraps everything in a case class but it happens automatically through implicits so it's ok for me.

Comment: @bali182 I would agree, it's cleaner; I didn't know you could do that